# What am I doing wrong coding a button on a WIX website to change a field value of a specific field in a WIX dataset?

Tags: onclick, dataset, save, velo

I have this code I have been tinkering around with but from the syntax, I have been trying to change my TAGID to 1 in the dataset.  Currently it is 0, I have been trying different things just to change the data in the dataset, nothing seems to be working..

```
$w.onReady( () => {
$w("#dataset1").onReady( () => {
$w("#dataset1").setFieldValue($w("#TagID", "1"));
$w("#dataset1").save()
```

} );

} );

Comment: Can you give us a bit more information about what you expect to happen and what is happening in actuality.

Comment: What is currently happening is that the page has a what is called a repeater/container with a image, title, description & button linked to a dataset.  I only have 2 records in the dataset, both have video files, images, & titles.  On the page the images & titles display perfectly.  The issue is when u click the button only the first record shows its video on another page, but for both buttons & probably if I add more records with video.  I need it to select the corresponding record & video for that button, but I noticed the behavior in the repeater keeps the buttons the same, so no butt1,2,etc

Comment: It doesn't sound like you need any code to do what you want. Seems like dynamic pages and connecting their datasets properly to the elements on the pages should work. It also might help us figure out what's going on if you send a link to the page(s) that aren't working. It's still a bit hard to tell what's going on from your description.

Comment: When you click the button to switch to the other page with the corresponding video, the video remains the first video in the recordset/dataset.   I am trying to code it to move through the dataset to the matching video, like the image does on the page I can see the different images.  But, every button to select the video only shows the 1st video of the 1st record.  Maybe it is because the dataset is linked to the dynamic page, if I embed the video on that page it would show.  I like the lightbox to show the next video though.